# creating a secondary variable when specific order of operations is needed

Tags: pandas

I am working with a typical data set (rows are observations and columns are variables)

I need to make a new variable based on two of the original variables in the data set. The logic needs to include the correct order of operations...i.e. if (a = 1 and b >= 10) or (a = 2 and b >= 20)... etc. I am able to do this easily in SAS (posted below), but am translating some work into python. My attempt is listed here. I also did not know how to handle NaN's in the logic. If either original variable is NaN, the new variable should be NaN too. I appreciate your help.

```
def OLDER4GRADE (row) :
    if (row['H1GI20'] == 7 and row['AGE'] >= 14)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 8 and row['AGE'] >= 15)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 9 and row['AGE'] >= 16)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 10 and row['AGE'] >= 17)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 11 and row['AGE'] >= 18)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 12 and row['AGE'] >= 19:
                return 1
          else :
                return 0
data['OLDER4GRADE'] = data.apply(lambda row: OLDER4GRADE (row), axis = 1)
```

HERE IS WHAT IT WOULD LOOK LIKE IN SAS

```
if H1GI20 EQ . or AGE1 eq . then OLDER4GRADE=.;
    else if (H1GI20=7 and AGE1 GE 14) or (H1GI20=8 and AGE1 GE 15) or (H1GI20=9 and AGE1 GE 16) or 
            (H1GI20=10 and AGE1 GE 17) or (H1GI20=11 and AGE1 GE 18) or (H1GI20=12 and AGE1 GE 19) 
        then OLDER4GRADE=1;
    else OLDER4GRADE=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first fix your code first:

```
import numpy as np

def OLDER4GRADE (row) :
    # handle `nan`
    # you check for first in the SAS code as well
    if np.isnan(row['H1GI20']) or np.isnan(row['AGE']): return np.nan

    if (row['H1GI20'] == 7 and row['AGE'] >= 14)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 8 and row['AGE'] >= 15)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 9 and row['AGE'] >= 16)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 10 and row['AGE'] >= 17)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 11 and row['AGE'] >= 18)
          or (row['H1GI20'] == 12 and row['AGE'] >= 19:
                return 1
          else :
                return 0

# apply the function is good enough, no need `lambda`
data['OLDER4GRADE'] = data.apply(OLDER4GRADE, axis = 1)
```

Now, for Pandas, it's recommended to avoid `apply` along the rows if possible. Your logic can be translated to:

```
# rows with `nan` in either column
invalid = data[['H1GI20', 'AGE']].isna().any(axis=1)

# the threshold for each category
thresholds = {
    7: 14,
    8: 15,
    9: 16,
   10: 17,
   11: 18,
   12: 19
}

# use `map` to turn `H1GI20` into respective threshold and compare
above_thresh = data['H1GI20'].map(thresholds) >= data['AGE']

data['OLDER4GRADE'] = np.where(invalid, np.nan, above_thresh.astype(int))
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you. I had imported numpy but thought that the new variable code was part of the pandas library. As a SAS programmer, I am still getting used to this concept of libraries. I am so grateful for your help.